# Get text from sticky note annotation

Tags: .net, wpf, annotations

For a sticky note [annotation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.annotations.annotation(v=vs.110).aspx) is there a way to extract the text from code behind?

Based on the accepted answer this is what I used

```
List<string> stickiesText = new List<string>();
foreach (Annotation annotation in service.Store.GetAnnotations())
{
    if (annotation.AnnotationType != null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(annotation.AnnotationType.ToString());
        if (annotation.AnnotationType.ToString().EndsWith("TextStickyNote"))
        {
            string base64Text = annotation.Cargos[1].Contents[0].InnerText;
            byte[] decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Text);

            MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream(decoded);

            Section section = XamlReader.Load(m) as Section;
            m.Close();

            TextRange range = new TextRange(section.ContentStart, section.ContentEnd);

            Debug.WriteLine(range.Text);
            stickiesText.Add(range.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Come on down vote.  What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. Yes, there is, but they don't make it easy. What a kerfuffle.

Based on the examples shown here: 
[Pro WPF 4.5 in C#: Windows Presentation Foundation in .NET 4.5, Matthew MacDonald](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=aPB9aEsLmMEC&pg=PA929&lpg=PA929&dq=wpf%20annotation%20innertext&source=bl&ots=cvENLF-sdD&sig=vP63Le3UI3Ea6U1fSGKuHxi3ZnI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAGoVChMIt6bUtcaUxwIVg0bbCh03MwVI#v=onepage&q=wpf%20annotation%20innertext&f=false), and here: [Introduction to Annotations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mehlhorn/archive/2006/03/11/549132.aspx).

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MvvmLight5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:annot="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Annotations;assembly=PresentationFramework"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MvvmLight5.Model"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MVVM Light Application"
        Width="Auto"
        Height="Auto"
        DataContext="{Binding Main,
                              Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
        Loaded="OnLoaded"
        Unloaded="OnUnloaded"
        mc:Ignorable="d ignore">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="300" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--  Viewer and simple content  -->

        <ToolBarTray Grid.Row="0">
            <!--  Annotations Toolbar  -->
            <ToolBar>
                <!--  StickyNote Operations  -->
                <GroupBox Header="Notes">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Width="30"
                                Command="annot:AnnotationService.CreateTextStickyNoteCommand"
                                Content="Text" />
                        <Button Width="30"
                                Command="annot:AnnotationService.CreateInkStickyNoteCommand"
                                Content="Ink" />
                        <Button Width="50"
                                Command="annot:AnnotationService.DeleteStickyNotesCommand"
                                Content="Delete" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </GroupBox>
            </ToolBar>
        </ToolBarTray>

        <FlowDocumentPageViewer Name="Viewer" Grid.Row="1">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>This is a simple example of a flow document and how you can add annotations to one.</Paragraph>
                <Paragraph>Later we'll get more complicated content...</Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </FlowDocumentPageViewer>

        <Button Grid.Row="2"
                Width="50"
                Height="50"
                Click="Button_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Codebehind:

```
// Turn Annotations On.
protected void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Make sure that an AnnotationService isn’t already enabled.
    AnnotationService service = AnnotationService.GetService(Viewer);

    if (service == null)
    {
        // (a) Create a Stream for the annotations to be stored in.
        AnnotationStream =
            new FileStream("annotations.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

        // (b) Create an AnnotationService on our
        // FlowDocumentPageViewer.
        service = new AnnotationService(Viewer);

        // (c) Create an AnnotationStore and give it the stream we
        // created. (Autoflush == false)
        AnnotationStore store = new XmlStreamStore(AnnotationStream);

        // (d) "Turn on annotations". Annotations will be persisted in
        // the stream created at (a).
        service.Enable(store);
    }
}

// Turn Annotations off.
protected void OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // (a) Check that an AnnotationService actually
    // existed and was Enabled.
    AnnotationService service =
    AnnotationService.GetService(Viewer);

    if (service != null && service.IsEnabled)
    {
        // (b) Flush changes to annotations to our stream.
        service.Store.Flush();
        // (c) Turn off annotations.
        service.Disable();
        // (d) Close our stream.
        AnnotationStream.Close();
    }
}

// The stream that we will store annotations in.
Stream AnnotationStream;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AnnotationService service =
    AnnotationService.GetService(Viewer);

    if (service != null && service.IsEnabled)
    {
        var annotation = service.Store.GetAnnotations().ElementAt(0);

        string base64Text = annotation.Cargos[1].Contents[0].InnerText;
        byte[] decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Text);

        MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream(decoded);

        Section section = XamlReader.Load(m) as Section;
        m.Close();

        TextRange range = new TextRange(section.ContentStart, section.ContentEnd);

        MessageBox.Show(range.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks.  I don't have time to test it right now but I will.